# Calling an object with static variables

Tags: java, class, object

I have recently begun coding a 3d computer game as part of my IB MYP personal project, Although I know a sufficient amount of Java I am having troubles getting my classes to work together. What I'm trying to do is create a class called block that defines a block and all it's properties, then call the block class for a basic description of a block every time I create an individual block with unique properties. I've tried extends which works, but I'd have to create a new extending class for every unique block, and I've tried creating an object but it won't work. All my searches turned up dry. Here's my code:

```
package src;

public class Block {
    //Defines a Block

    double id; //Full = type, decimal = subtype
    String type; //Name/tooltip
    int sound; //Type of sound played on collision
    int light; //Ammount of light given off
    boolean breaks; //Wether the block is breakable
    boolean solid; //Wether the block has collision detection

}
```

How can I go about calling this object multiple times in a different class, each time with all the values slightly different?

Comment: Create multiple objects?  I don't get it...

Comment: I don't see anything `static` here at all. This code doesn't actually _do_ anything, either; it just defines a class. How are you trying to _use_ it?

Comment: So you want to have multiple different objects that are like Block? Like Block1, Block2, Block3, etc or you want to just create...multiple Block objects with different values for id,type,etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a constructor for a Block as follows:

```
public Block(double id, String type, int sound, int light, boolean breaks, boolean solid) {
    this.id = id;
    this.type = type;
    this.sound = sound;
    this.light = light;
    this.breaks = breaks;
    this.solid = solid;
}
```

With this, you can create as many different kinds of Blocks as you want.

Comment: This worked! I knew there was a simple fix. Thank you for bringing it out into the light :)

Answer (score 0):

**1.** If the values keep changing, its better u make this class **Abstract**.

**2.** Then you can have a custom **constructor to initialize the state of every object differently.**

eg:

`public Block(double id, String type, int sound, int light, boolean breaks, boolean solid)`

**3.** Have **getter methods** so that you can fetch the values of the variables.

Comment: Thank you, I'll need this too as some of my classes will involve multiple different variations of the object. Thank you :)